# Where are the files being currently downloaded or unsuccessfully partial download files from Telegram Web being stored on my PC?

Tags: download, telegram-messenger, webclient

UPDATE_2: Even on closing Telegram Web and reentering, I get the same problem of empty clicks on *Download* link under the same files that had the problem before.

UPDATE: Some of my friends have observed and confirmed it to be a problem on Telegram's side and not on the client's system.

I had given multiple videos on download but all of them were stuck at 0 although I could see the network activity shoot through the roof. So I thought maybe when they are done downloading, I'd get a prompt asking me for the save directory.

But to my dismay, nothing happened and even worse, I got the same 'Download' link written instead of 'Save File'. 
I tried reloading the page and now the download starts again. God knows how many GBs I have wasted on it, hence I was wondering if there's any way to redeem those files? 
Thanks!

OS - Win 10.1(x64) Browser - Chrome 56.0

Comment: Issue #173 seems to state the same problem although it looks like Luke is distressed by the mobile version. How did they close it btw - it's not resolved? [Check it out](https://github.com/overtake/telegram/issues/173)

Comment: I tested Google Chrome 56 on Windows 10 with a very small video. It successfully downloaded it to my Downloads folder.

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users[User Profile]\AppData\Local\Packages\TelegramMessengerLLP.TelegramDesktop_t4vj0pshhgkwm\LocalCache\Roaming\Telegram Desktop UWP

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Telegram regularly and need to download the files regularly, you should opt for downloading telegram desktop app. 
If you are using telegram desktop app, the downloaded files get downloaded under the folder "telegram desktop" under your download folder. 
Much easy to locate.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven’t downloaded the Telegram Desktop app from the Telegram website, do that first.
Then, to find your downloaded Telegram videos go to:
This PC > Downloads > Telegram Desktop > ChatExport_[the folder name will show date video/videos were exported - this is presuming you have already exported the video/videos you want to keep) > video files
[NB: To export your videos, navigate to the group or chat where the video is that you want to download and save (export).
Click the icon menu on the top right corner (the 3 vertical dots), and select Export Chat History. You will get to choose what you want to export e.g. video or image.]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, so I was searching for the location and finally i found it:

```
C:\Users\[YourUserName]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\https_web.telegram.org_0.indexeddb.blob\
```

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\https_web.telegram.org_0.indexeddb.blob\
```